# IndexMatch, multiple criteria - returns #N/A in all instances

Tags: excel

**OBJECTIVE**

Perform IndexMatch procedure on two criteria to return a Currency Exchange Rate. 
The two criteria will be "Currency" and "Date" (since currency exchange rates fluctuate month-to-month).

**APPROACH**

1. Create a table with Currencies (rows) and Dates (columns)
2. Perform an IndexMatch on two inputs (Currency, Date) and retreive relevant exchange rate
3. Multiple Local Currencies by Exchange rate to get USD converion.

**CODE/Layout**

*Inputs*

[image]

*Exchange Rate Table*

[image]

*Excel Formula*

Simple:

```
{=INDEX(K3:N5,MATCH("GBP"&"1 2015",K4:K5&L3:N3,0))}
```

or Matrix Multiplication:

```
{=INDEX(L4:N5,MATCH(1,(Q2=K4:K5)*(Q3=L3:N3),0))}
```

---

*Expected Output*

> 1.1

*Actual Output (see: "Exchange Rate" in INPUTS*

> N/A

---

**NOTES**

- I've confirmed that both "GBP" and "1 2015" are text-based
- I've used both [a matrix multiplication approach](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/) and a [simpler approach](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/), both of which currently aren't working.

**QUESTIONS**

1. I tend to believe the culprit is the fact that I am trying to extract currencies from a 2x3 table (as opposed to a single column). However, shouldn't the Matrix Multiplication formula take care of this issue? Any Suggestions and/or error you see that I currently do not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an array formula just use all three criteria of the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(L4:N5,MATCH(Q2,K4:K5,0),MATCH(Q3,L3:N3,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I will note that the formula only works by referencing COLUMNS first, then ROWS (e.g the first MATCH formula has to be for CURRENCY and the second MATCH column has to be for DATE). Otherwise, this formula work and will be my preferred method moving forward. Thanks!